# How to Compute the Following Limit

Tags: limits

How do I compute this limit

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^n\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{e}}\right)^{2n}}{n! 9^n} = 0?$$

My intuition tells me I'm going to have to use this idea...

$$c^n\ll n!\ll n^n,$$ for $c>1$. So I'm considering how I can use this to help me.

Comment: Stirling's approximation should be able to help you here.

Comment: The first thing to note is that the $3$ and the $9$ cancel each other out.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use Stirling's Approximation:

$$
n! \;\; \approx \;\; n^n e^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}.
$$

Comment: The expression ends up as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I'd like to avoid doing the OP's homework for them...

Comment: Thanks! Got it! I just lacked the knowledge of this approximation, but now it's easy to do!

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to *study* the limit; after looking at the expression one first can simplify it a bit

$$ \frac{n^n (\frac{3}{\sqrt{e}})^{2n}}{n! 3^{2n}}=\frac{n^n (\frac{3}{\sqrt{e}})^{2n}}{n! 3^{2n}}=\frac{n^n }{n! (\sqrt{e})^{2n}}=\frac{n^n }{n!e^n}$$

Can you proceed now?

Comment: I understand using the stirling's approximation, but I do not understand this approach

Comment: Of course, you can use Stirling's approximation, but other methods available, see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2636861/evaluation-of-limit-without-using-stirlings-approximation?rq=1.